# How can i make a "github client" with Octokit.Net in C#?

Tags: c#, git, octokit.net

I use the tool Octokit.net to make an own GitHub client and my question is how can I delete the files in the repository when they aren't in the local folder anymore?

This is the code I already have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Octokit;
using Octokit.Internal;
using Octokit.Reactive;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]).Wait();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string rootPath, string owner, string repo, string branch)
    {
        var github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("repository"));
        var user = await github.User.Get("username");

        github.Credentials = new Credentials("token");

        var contents = await github.Repository.Content.GetAllContents(owner, repo);

        foreach(var githubFilePath in contents)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(githubFilePath);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(contents);

        UpdateFull().Wait();

        // Update a whole folder
        async Task UpdateFull()
        {
            updateGithub(rootPath).Wait();

            async Task updateGithub(string path)
            {
                var localContents = Directory.GetFiles(path);
                var localContentFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);


                var headMasterRef = "heads/master";
                var masterReference = await github.Git.Reference.Get(owner, repo, headMasterRef);
                var latestCommit = await github.Git.Commit.Get(owner, repo, masterReference.Object.Sha);

                var nt = new NewTree { BaseTree = latestCommit.Tree.Sha };


                // Add items based on blobs

                AddDirectoryToTree(path, path + "\\", nt).Wait();

               var rootTree = await github.Git.Tree.Create(owner, repo, nt);
                // Create Commit
                var newCommit = new NewCommit("Commit test with several files", rootTree.Sha, masterReference.Object.Sha);
                var commit = await github.Git.Commit.Create(owner, repo, newCommit);

                await github.Git.Reference.Update(owner, repo, headMasterRef, new ReferenceUpdate(commit.Sha));

            }

            async Task AddDirectoryToTree(string DirectoryPath, string RootPath, NewTree Tree)
            {

                //  all direct files in the folder
                //
                var localContents = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath);

                foreach (var filePath in localContents)
                {
                    string sExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToUpper();
                    string sFilename = filePath.Replace(RootPath, "").Replace(@"\", "/");                 


                    Console.WriteLine("File(Local): " + sFilename);

                    switch (sExtension)
                    {
                        default:
                            // Create text blob
                            var textBlob = new NewBlob { Encoding = EncodingType.Utf8, Content = File.ReadAllText(filePath) };
                            var textBlobRef = await github.Git.Blob.Create(owner, repo, textBlob);

                            Tree.Tree.Add(new NewTreeItem { Path = sFilename, Mode = "100644", Type = TreeType.Blob, Sha = textBlobRef.Sha });
                            break;

                        case ".PNG":
                        case ".JPEG":
                        case ".JPG":
                            // For image, get image content and convert it to base64
                            var imgBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
                            // Create image blob
                            var imgBlob = new NewBlob { Encoding = EncodingType.Base64, Content = (imgBase64) };
                            var imgBlobRef = await github.Git.Blob.Create(owner, repo, imgBlob);

                            Tree.Tree.Add(new NewTreeItem { Path = sFilename, Mode = "100644", Type = TreeType.Blob, Sha = imgBlobRef.Sha });

                            break;
                    }
                }



                //  subfolder
                //
                var localContentFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(DirectoryPath);

                foreach (string subDirPath in localContentFolders)
                {
                    AddDirectoryToTree(subDirPath, RootPath, Tree).Wait();
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Successfully commited Files");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Do I maybe need to add a new foreach for the Github repository and make then an if statement to look at the repository and local folder? :o

Would appreciateif you guys could help me with that! :D